# K&R exercise 1-22 Hints

Tags: c

The exercise  states as follows

> *Write a program to "fold" long input lines in two or more shorter lines after the non-last blank character that occurs before the n-th columns of input. Make sure your program does something intelligent with very long lines, and if there are no blanks or tabs before the specified column.*

My question is on how to implement the `foldStrings` function. I have tried some things but none of them worked.

Can you give me some hints on how to do this, but please don't write the solution down I want to figure it myself.

I have written some code but I am stuck at the folding part

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int getline(char s[], int lim);
void emptystring(char s[]);
void foldStrings(char s[],int len);
int main(){
        int len ;
        char line[255];
        while((len = getline(line,255))>0)
               {
                    foldStrings(line,len);
               }

return 0;
}
int getline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int c , i ;
    for( i = 0 ; i < lim-1 && ( c = getchar()) != EOF && c !='\n';++i)
                s[i] = c;

    if ( c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

void foldStrings(char s[], int len)
{


}
void emptystring(char s[])
{
        int i;
        int len = strlen(s);
        for( i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i){
            s[i] = 0 ;
        }
}
```

I am stuck at the `foldStrings` function.

P.S *I am using the empty string function to print the lines, so print a segmented line and then empty it, fill it up again and print it and so on*.

---

**Update**

I have  tried doing the `foldStrings`, here is one of my implementations

```
void foldStrings(char s[], int len)
{
    int i  ;
    char temp[255];
    for(i = 1;i < len-1 ;++i)
    {
        if( i % 16 != 0)
        {
            temp[i-1] = s[i-1];
        }
        else if(i%16 == 0)
        {
            printf("%s",temp)
            emptystring(temp);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Tried some ideas , but none of them worked

Comment: What did you try?  In what way didn't they work?  Show us the best effort code and explain how it didn't work.  Maybe you should show some of your sample data, too (5 lines should be enough).  What width are you planning to use in your testing?  (Somewhere in the 20-30 character range is likely a good choice.)

Comment: Folding is mostly done on a word level, so instead of reading the whole line or one character at a time read one word at a time and just check if it fits in current line, start at next line only when it doesn't. You would need to split words in the middle only if they were longer than your current line length.

Answer (score 0):

When `getline()` is done, `s` is not necessarily null character terminated.

```
    // for( i = 0 ; i < lim-1 && ...
    for( i = 0 ; i < lim-2 && ( c = getchar()) != EOF && c !='\n';++i)

    ...

    s[i] = '\0'; // add
    return i;
```

Same for `foldStrings()`.  missing null character.

```
    temp[i-1] = s[i-1];
    temp[i] = '\0'; // add
```

Other problems may exist

Answer (score 0):

This exercise is a little challenging.

At first, you don't need to buffer at all, as you only have two kinds of read chars (blank/non blank) and for a non blank character you always have to print it, so your main loop can be something like

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

(much the style all exercises in K&R are written)

look that when blank character are input, you only have to count them, and reset the counter on `\n` input.

As you ask not to reveal the final solution, I'll commit on that, but the trick is to count characters as you read the line, outputting on nonblanks (and counting) and not outputting (but only counting) on blank characters.  If the character read is a blank and you have passed the limit, you'll fold the line (emit a `\n`)

## EDITION 1

In my first attempt to write the code I discovered that the pattern `blank->nonblank` crossing the maximum line length boundary makes the need to break the line at the point of the first blank character and remember all the nonblank characters read so far.  In that case, I'll need at most, the maximum output line length of storage (to store the non blank characters that happen to be in the data when we reach the maximum line length and have to break the line), and a maximum output line length of them have to be stored, as if I get more, for sure the line must be broken before that point.

My first attempt will be to store the number of blank characters read so far, followed by a buffer of maximum output line length (not input line length, which is unbounded, as specified in the problem).  The possible statuses will be:  (follow next edition of page)